# SSIS - Mapping of paramater values to a configuration does not work

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2017

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio Community 2019 (16.11.8)
together with SSIS extension 3.15 and at some point in time (can't say exaxt date/time)
the possibility to map project parameters to a configuration stopped working.

I can add new parameter mappings using the dialog but when clicking ok and reopening the dialog, the parameter is gone. Parameter mappings added earlier stay unchanged.

Here an example:

Open dialog

[image]

Then add a parameter

[image]

Parameter has been added:

[image]

Close and open dialog again:

[image]

One of my colleagues tested this with same software versions, problem is the same there.

Maybe anybody already knows this or can give me a hint if I do something wrong or if there is a workaround.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I can't say I have ever experienced this. My best guess if you are pressing "Cancel" instead of "Ok", and/or after you make the change are closing and not saving the project.

Comment: If I click Cancel nothing changes and closing the project also doesn't change something. I just realized that all parameters which are working are of course stored inside the .dtproj file while when adding new ones now, no file changes occur. And I also realized that if I try to add all remaining parameters to the mapping, some are added but not all. The ones which cannot be added remain as a problem.

Comment: Seems to affect only projects with many project parameters, if I have only a few parameters it is working. And for the projects with many project parameters if I remove all and new ones, it is working again. I hope this is not the only option to fix this as I would have to change all related tasks I fear.

Comment: After some additional investigation it seems that we could fix it for two of us by opening one of the affected solutions, then remove all parameters, save, close the project and revert the project via gitKraken to the last code version. This fixed it for all other projects also, don't understand it, looks like it's a cache problem in Visual Studio or SSIS extension and not project-specific. Maybe anyone knows something about such a cache mechanism and how to clean/repair it with a more common method...

Comment: Perhaps your Source Control Software had made the project file Read Only in some way, and as a result the settings weren't being saved. We have a couple of projects at the office that use file locking due to their nature and merge conflicts are an absolute [redacted] to resolve. As only a couple of people work on the projects it just easier overall; if one of us forget to check in we just throw something at them ;) . When the project or solution are read-only but the file you're working on isn't and you make a change that effects both, it can have some... Interesting results/behaviours.

Comment: ok, interesting point, when we have someone who has this problem again (or still) I will also consider this, thanks for the hint. Currently I try to find someone who still has the problem to test this.